# Revoked All Privileges On Database But Still The User Can Create Table

Tags: database, postgresql, crud, privileges

I am new at Postgresql that's why I can't figure out some privileges here.

Database called `Denemedb23` is already created. I created the user `NoxUser`.

I executed these commands:

1. `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE Denemedb23 FROM public;`
2. `GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE Denemedb23 TO NoxUser;`

I want `Noxuser` just to be able to login to the database and he should not be able to create table/function etc. But `NoxUser` can create a table in the database.

Could you help me to figure out why?

Comment: Is NoxUser a superuser?

Comment: No it is not @Bert-JanStroop

Comment: You should add to your question what `NoxUser`  is allowed to do besides login?

Comment: I already said what I wanted,
"I want Noxuser just to be able to login to the database" 
I want to show which commands will be able to do this condition after I want to grant privileges for NoxUser

Comment: @BegümNurKadem Only connect and no other privileges to interact with anything in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Privileges on the database are one thing. Privileges on things in it is another. This:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE Denemedb23 FROM public;
```

Effectively means this:

```
REVOKE CREATE ON DATABASE Denemedb23 FROM public;
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE Denemedb23 FROM public;
REVOKE TEMPORARY ON DATABASE Denemedb23 FROM public;
```

Meanings of these you can see below and [in the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html#DDL-PRIV-CREATE). I'm guessing you could've expected `CREATE` to mean something else.

> `CREATE`
> For databases, allows new schemas and publications to be created within the database, and allows trusted extensions to be installed within the database.

> `CONNECT`
> Allows the grantee to connect to the database. This privilege is checked at connection startup (in addition to checking any restrictions imposed by pg_hba.conf).

> `TEMPORARY`
> Allows temporary tables to be created while using the database.

If you wanted to lock them out, you need to revoke their privileges on schema/object level, [for example](https://dbfiddle.uk/0yB78R2x):

```
revoke all on all tables in schema public from NoxUser;
revoke all on all routines in schema public from NoxUser;
revoke all on all sequences in schema public from NoxUser;
revoke all on schema public from NoxUser;
```

On schema level, create means something else, as outlined in the doc linked earlier:

> `CREATE` For schemas, allows new objects to be created within the schema. To rename an existing object, you must own the object and have this privilege for the containing schema.

The last command will revoke that on `public`, but you might want to inspect other schemas as well. You can also create a schema named `NoxUser`, and by default their non-schema-qualified commands will target that schema thanks to [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH), before taking a look at `public`. Refer to [schema usage patterns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATTERNS) for more.

If you only wish to stop them from creating in `public` while retaining all access beside that, use only that one revoke.

```
revoke create on schema public from NoxUser;
```

Comment: What I got from the OP's question is they did not want `NoxUser` to create objects, not prevent them from using objects. The `revoke all on all ...` statements would prevent the user from accessing the objects. Seems to me `revoke create on schema <schema_name> from <some_role>` is all that is necessary.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver true, I assumed this is the kind of situation where they wish to lock them out, clean things up and let them back in once their access has been sufficiently restrained. I clarified that now

Answer (score -1):

The CONNECT permission in PostgreSQL enables a user to establish a connection to a database, but it does not provide the user the power to create tables or carry out other tasks.

In your instance, you have given NoxUser the CONNECT privilege and removed all database rights from the public role. However, the CREATE privilege on the schema is required in order to create tables.

So, make sure the user does not have the CREATE privilege on the schema in order to accomplish your aim of enabling NoxUser to connect to the database but prevent them from creating tables.

Run these commands, these guarantee that although NoxUser can connect to the Denemedb23 database but  cannot create tables in the public schema.

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM public;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE Denemedb23 TO NoxUser;
```

Hope it's helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried these commands with super user ,but still NoxUser is able to create table :(